# Get a bookmark to load a page and run javascript on it

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, bookmarks

Currently I have a page that I visit often, and a `javascript:` bookmarklet that I also use every time I visit the page. For example:

```
javascript:(function(){getElementByName("profile-name").value="Maurdekye";})()
```

And every time I click my bookmark to go to this page, I also click this bookmarklet to automatically fill out this information. I'd like to know if it's possible to have both of these actions in a single bookmark. I tried setting the `location.href` property to redirect to the webpage, and putting the above function in `document.onload`. It redirects when I click the bookmark, but it doesn't run the code. This is what I have tried so far;

```
javascript:(function(){location.href="https://my.website.net/login.html";document.onload=(function(){getElementByName("profile-name").value="Maurdekye";});})()
```

Comment: Not possible through a bookmarklet. You'd need to build an extension or a greasemonkey/tampermonkey userscript.